# FB Like button url not working in IE8 (using iframe)

Tags: iframe, facebook-like

I'm using the following iframe tag in my portlet jsp:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=
  <%=url%>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=286&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=35"
  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:286px; 
  height:35px;" allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

Clicking on like button in firefox redirects to FB login page. However in IE8 it redirects to a blank page.

Following is the url I copied from IE8 browser which shows blank page:

```
http://www.facebook.com/connect/connect_to_external_page_widget_loggedin.php?social_plugin=like&external_page_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fweb%2Fbates%2Fprofile#_=_
```

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling IE Protected Mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=
  <%=url%>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=286&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=35"
  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:286px; 
  height:35px;" allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Correct me, but isn't this exactly the same as the code provided in the question?